# PHP Form Helper Class

Tags: php, forms, class, helper

I need a simple PHP Form Helper Class to build forms. I googled around and all the comes up are links from the main PHP frameworks. I looked at all their classes but they seem needlessly overly complicated. Yes, I looked at this too: http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/ No good :)

Have you ever run into something simple fort his?

Comment: What are your requirements, exactly?

Comment: Simple PHP Form Class that I can use in different PHP scripts I will write.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about such a "helper class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we use for all our websites: [CodeIgniter form_heper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: Yeah, looked at that - complicated.

Comment: "Complicated" is all relative I suppose.

Comment: Simple would be a form class that produces HTML form elements.

Comment: The CodeIgniter form_helper is pretty good actually. I'll use that. Thanks Alien!

Comment: How can I use this helper outside from CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar for a project some months ago, but had to build one myself. You can browse the source code  and download the helper at https://github.com/mawuli-ypa/Php-html-class. Example:

```
  $html = new html;  
  // OR $html = new html('div',array('id'=>'iv id here','class'=>'div class here','text'=>'div contents here'))


   //create basic elements
  $html->create("h1",array('text'=>"mawuli-ypa","class"=>"big","style"=>"font-    size:30px"));
  $html->create("h1",array('text'=>"@koceptone.com","class"=>"big","style"=>"font-size:20px"));
```

Forms:

```
 $html->create("form",array("enctype"=>"","multipart/form-data","method"=>"POST","action"=>"upload.php"));
 /* now render elements */
 $html->buildAll();
```

This was an experimental helper but was quite useful. The helper will be updated soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend Form class from [ATK UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui). The class aims to do the following:

- Build form HTML using Semantic UI (supporting vertical, horizontal, multi-column and custom layouts)
- Direct integration with data storage (SQL, NoSQL), handle of type conversions (such as dates, drop-downs, auto-complete fields). Also validation.
- Integration between PHP and JavaScript events. You specify what happens on form submission - redirect, reload, closing modal, etc.
- Extensibility. There are support for [file uploads](https://github.com/atk4/filestore) which integrates with Flysystem, custom fields, audit and more.

(more info [in the doc](http://agile-ui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form.html))

The implementation is not tied into any specific full-stack framework, so can be used in any PHP project. There is [integration into wordpress too](https://www.atkwp.com).

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Form from the Zend Framework. Maybe not exactly simple yet powerful. I think there is no simple class because forms overall can become very complex.

Comment: Yes, power comes with complication. Need something simpler.

Comment: Well, the classes are modular, so if you just need a simple element, then there is a single class for just that element. If you just need a radio element you can use Zend_Form_Element_Radio() alone.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are complicated... they just are. You start simple and then you realize you need constraints and validation. Then you realize that the availability of one field depends on the value of another, and so on. If all you need is bare simplicity, then it shouldn't take much effort to write your own form field tags and write some PHP to process the input. That is about as simple as it's going to get.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this library and it works fine.

http://helpers.theframework.es/helper-form/examples/

```
use TheFramework\Helpers\HelperForm;
use TheFramework\Helpers\HelperLabel;
use TheFramework\Helpers\HelperInputText;
use TheFramework\Helpers\HelperSelect;

$arFields = [];

$oAux = new HelperLabel("txtNameId","My label for Name");
$oAux->add_class("custom-control");
$arFields[] = $oAux;

$oAux = new HelperInputText();
$oAux->add_class("col-4");
$oAux->add_class("form-control");
$oAux->add_extras("placeholder","Eg. Eduardo A. F.");
$oAux->set_id("txtNameId");
$oAux->set_name("txtName");
$arFields[] = $oAux;

$arFields["sel"] = new HelperSelect([""=>"choose...","one"=>"One","two"=>"Two","three"=>"Three"]);
$arFields["sel"]->add_class("form-control col-4");

$arFields["textarea"] = new TheFramework\Helpers\HelperTextarea();
$arFields["textarea"]->add_class("form-control");
$arFields["textarea"]->add_extras("placeholder","Your comments");
$arFields["textarea"]->set_id("txaComments");

$oForm = new HelperForm();
$oForm->add_class("col-6");
$oForm->add_style("border:1px dashed #4f9fcf;");
$oForm->add_style("padding:5px;");
$oForm->set_id("myForm");
$oForm->set_method("some_method");
$oForm->set_enctype("myEncType");
$oForm->add_controls($arFields);
$oForm->show();
```